# Is there anyway to pass an array as multiple arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Let's say I have an array `[2, 3]`, and I want to pass that into a function. Not as `function([2, 3])`, as `function(2, 3)`. Is there anyway to do that, like
`function(pass(array))`?

Comment: Did you mean `function(*array)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Yes! Thank you quamrana and James!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out (it utilizes the unpacking operator `*`):

```
array = [2, 3]
function(*array)
```